# Plot time series of zoo object in subplots ignoring NA:s

Tags: r, plot, na, zoo, subplot

I have a zoo object containing 10 groups, where every group contains NA-values, I'm trying to create a plot where the values from every group is plotted against time in a subplot, ignoring the NA:s. I would like all groups to be plotted over the full time period, eaven if it only contains values for a part of the period. I have tryed to use na.exclude and na.pass but it just doesn't work.

This is my data:

```
structure(c(-4.10947262625989, NA, -6.35834864986063, NA, -5.91266537625275, 
NA, -6.52008097909069, NA, -5.2902016879408, NA, -3.11303759188572, 
NA, -0.306205546663778, NA, -1.16249420065793, NA, -3.33688404352456, 
NA, -8.13394337994639, NA, -4.97829512928346, NA, -4.91184324092269, 
NA, -0.426243026538591, NA, -2.47957454922956, NA, -3.3329046491404, 
NA, -4.36366791265756, NA, -6.1055782340265, NA, -6.2094702018437, 
NA, -2.96526179126904, NA, -3.36132436304139, NA, -1.06078300406145, 
NA, -0.656336560364218, NA, -2.04074053746388, NA, -4.99967426633704, 
NA, -4.04800553172208, NA, -3.31189396136818, NA, -2.36440148960283, 
NA, -1.18900512784083, NA, -3.05795867861728, NA, NA, NA, -4.97174143754589, 
NA, -6.23509102350769, NA, -5.89843588741174, NA, -4.18645165800088, 
NA, -2.0212883057441, NA, -1.04550830382834, NA, -1.27999574705108, 
NA, -3.14638335358303, NA, -3.86222685146702, NA, -4.21772272823727, 
NA, -2.58543072976183, NA, -2.48846140494414, NA, -2.22821228166982, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -5.28108123680546, NA, -6.06192246724695, 
NA, -4.56130486243214, NA, -2.74677229492713, NA, -1.7789934443997, 
NA, -1.44728905496209, NA, -2.08633334103407, NA, -2.99380214399451, 
NA, -4.04643083407379, NA, -3.43524805580059, NA, -2.5415459951728, 
NA, -2.75734663004611, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -5.1830394775654, 
NA, -4.8164568203158, NA, -3.18719721106969, NA, -2.37873600997152, 
NA, -2.00135150333387, NA, -2.08291969862349, NA, -2.25691836415158, 
NA, -3.23822518515935, NA, -3.52333679362043, NA, -3.32001852877501, 
NA, -2.75530170365368, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -4.60120959896844, 
NA, -3.49697326894922, NA, -2.75887253351057, NA, -2.4962239838783, 
NA, -2.46788431125548, NA, -2.2640901134155, NA, -2.51329703125672, 
NA, -2.9862663107103, NA, -3.44439144612439, NA, -3.3266447343254, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -3.60784867185276, 
NA, -3.07207080168394, NA, -2.81269574155185, NA, -2.86157315340287, 
NA, -2.52790961472606, NA, -2.49684311839687, NA, -2.42078499136711, 
NA, -2.98180846872684, NA, -3.40641608489269, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -3.23223720384766, NA, -3.10313101000138, 
NA, -3.11608282590682, NA, -2.85334053214087, NA, -2.70174906729397, 
NA, -2.44411673514141, NA, -2.46253325647867, NA, -2.99992356599436, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -3.24370475890788, 
NA, -3.36581515217865, NA, -3.08076778703707, NA, -2.98623115636078, 
NA, -2.61154777515114, NA, -2.49224003994964, NA, -2.52774960963835, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, -3.45699179158273, NA, -3.28582189621058, NA, -3.19061533966329, 
NA, -2.87595330453915, NA, -2.63679933171846, NA, -2.55051771717749, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(29L, 10L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("structure(c(-4.10947262625989, -7.35834864986063, -5.91266537625275, ", 
    "structure(c(-4.36366791265756, -6.1055782340265, -6.2094702018437, ", 
    "structure(c(-4.97174143754589, -6.23509102350769, -5.89843588741174, ", 
    "structure(c(-5.28108123680546, -6.06192246724695, -4.56130486243214, ", 
    "structure(c(-5.1830394775654, -4.8164568203158, -3.18719721106969, ", 
    "structure(c(-4.60120959896844, -3.49697326894922, -2.75887253351057, ", 
    "structure(c(-3.60784867185276, -3.07207080168394, -2.81269574155185, ", 
    "structure(c(-3.23223720384766, -3.10313101000138, -3.11608282590682, ", 
    "structure(c(-3.24370475890788, -3.36581515217865, -3.08076778703707, ", 
    "structure(c(-3.45699179158273, -3.28582189621058, -3.19061533966329, "
    )), index = structure(c(17393.375, 17393.875, 17394.375, 
17394.875, 17395.375, 17395.875, 17396.375, 17396.875, 17397.375, 
17397.875, 17398.375, 17398.875, 17399.375, 17399.875, 17400.375, 
17400.875, 17401.375, 17401.875, 17402.375, 17402.875, 17403.375, 
17403.875, 17404.375, 17404.875, 17405.375, 17405.875, 17406.375, 
17406.875, 17407.375), format = structure(c("m/d/y", "h:m:s"), .Names = c("dates", 
"times")), origin = c(1, 1, 1970), class = c("chron", "dates", 
"times")), class = "zoo")
```

Does anyone have some ideas on how to do this in r? Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your data, there's always an NA between values, so when you say "ignore NAs", I'm assuming you mean connecting the dots even if there's an NA in between.

First, we load the zoo library explicitly:

```
library(zoo)
```

Then, we save the data into a variable:

```
z <- structure(c(-4.10947262625989, NA, -6.35834864986063, NA, -5.91266537625275, 
            NA, -6.52008097909069, NA, -5.2902016879408, NA, -3.11303759188572, 
            NA, -0.306205546663778, NA, -1.16249420065793, NA, -3.33688404352456, 
            NA, -8.13394337994639, NA, -4.97829512928346, NA, -4.91184324092269,
# I'm not pasting the whole data block, but you get the idea
```

Then, we use zoo to interpolate all the NAs between existing values, but we don't interpolate missing values in the head/tail:

```
filled <- na.fill(z, list(NA, "extend", NA))
```

The zoo package has a function for plotting all the series in a zoo object

```
autoplot(filled, facets = NULL) + 
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

So here's what we would get back:
[image: zoo chart]